# Long string gets truncated automatically in Firefox while in Google chrome its working perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services, json

Below is my block of code where I am retrieving one json string through web service.
 Yes it is in XML tag. So I read this tag and parse it using jQuery parser **jQuery.parseJSON(xml.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);**

```
 $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:14734/services/Project.asmx/GetProjectHistory",
        dataType: "xml",
        processData: true,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { ajaxError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown); },
        success: function(xml) {
            var t = xml.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            alert(t);
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(xml.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
            GetProjectsActivity(data);
            GetUpcommingTask(data);
            // alert(data);
        }
    });
```

I am getting full string in response as I expected. But in FireFox I see that string is truncated.
 **jQuery.parseJSON(xml.getElementsByTagName("string")
[0].firstChild.nodeValue);**

Truncated string is as below ...

> {"List":{ "Table": [ { "HDate": "15 Sep ", "ActionDateTime":
>   "/Date(1316049833340+0530)/", "HTime": "06:53:53", "UserName":
>   "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name": "yrr", "EntityType": "Project ",
>   "ActionType": "is Deleted", "ID": 445, "hID": 825 }, { "HDate": "15
>   Sep ", "ActionDateTime": "/Date(1316049831280+0530)/", "HTime":
>   "06:53:51", "UserName": "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name": "yrr",
>   "EntityType": "Project ", "ActionType": "is Deleted", "ID": 445,
>   "hID": 824 }, { "HDate": "15 Sep ", "ActionDateTime":
>   "/Date(1316047802467+0530)/", "HTime": "06:20:02", "UserName":
>   "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name": "yrr", "EntityType": "Project ",
>   "ActionType": "is Inserted", "ID": 445, "hID": 823 }, { "HDate": "14
>   Sep ", "ActionDateTime": "/Date(1315984624977+0530)/", "HTime":
>   "12:47:04", "UserName": "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name":
>   "1315049911_administrator.png", "EntityType": "File ", "ActionType":
>   "is Inserted", "ID": 51, "hID": 819 }, { "HDate": "14 Sep ",
>   "ActionDateTime": "/Date(1315984411087+0530)/", "HTime": "12:43:31",
>   "UserName": "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name":
>   "1315049980_coraline.png", "EntityType": "File ", "ActionType": "is
>   Inserted", "ID": 50, "hID": 818 }, { "HDate": "14 Sep ",
>   "ActionDateTime": "/Date(1315983619353+0530)/", "HTime": "12:30:19",
>   "UserName": "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name": "stage3", "EntityType":
>   "Stage ", "ActionType": "is Deleted", "ID": 1266, "hID": 817 }, {
>   "HDate": "14 Sep ", "ActionDateTime": "/Date(1315983554447+0530)/",
>   "HTime": "12:29:14", "UserName": "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name":
>   "fgdfgdfgdfg", "EntityType": "Step ", "ActionType": "is Inserted",
>   "ID": 1284, "hID": 816 }, { "HDate": "14 Sep ", "ActionDateTime":
>   "/Date(1315982622400+0530)/", "HTime": "12:13:42", "UserName":
>   "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name": "sdfsdssdfs", "EntityType": "Step ",
>   "ActionType": "is Inserted", "ID": 1281, "hID": 799 }, { "HDate": "14
>   Sep ", "ActionDateTime": "/Date(1315982619307+0530)/", "HTime":
>   "12:13:39", "UserName": "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name": "sdfsdssdfs",
>   "EntityType": "Step ", "ActionType": "is Inserted", "ID": 1280, "hID":
>   798 }, { "HDate": "14 Sep ", "ActionDateTime":
>   "/Date(1315980254543+0530)/", "HTime": "11:34:14", "UserName":
>   "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name": "stage1", "EntityType": "Stage ",
>   "ActionType": "is Deleted", "ID": 1255, "hID": 792 }, { "HDate": "14
>   Sep ", "ActionDateTime": "/Date(1315970910450+0530)/", "HTime":
>   "08:58:30", "UserName": "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name": "stage",
>   "EntityType": "Stage ", "ActionType": "is Updated", "ID": 1251, "hID":
>   741 }, { "HDate": "14 Sep ", "ActionDateTime":
>   "/Date(1315970792030+0530)/", "HTime": "08:56:32", "UserName":
>   "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name": "step", "EntityType": "Step ",
>   "ActionType": "is Updated", "ID": 1252, "hID": 740 }, { "HDate": "14
>   Sep ", "ActionDateTime": "/Date(1315970754793+0530)/", "HTime":
>   "08:55:54", "UserName": "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name": "step",
>   "EntityType": "Step ", "ActionType": "is Updated", "ID": 1252, "hID":
>   739 }, { "HDate": "14 Sep ", "ActionDateTime":
>   "/Date(1315970743077+0530)/", "HTime": "08:55:43", "UserName":
>   "Dev1Intellial", "Project_Name": "step", "EntityType": "Step ",
>   "ActionType": "is Up

Yes, it is not a valid json string so when jQuery.parseJson function trying to parse it then it throws errors due to the invalid json format.

**In Google chrome all goes well without error. Problem is only with FireFox.**

Comment: Alerting string with truncation is not the same as truncation of string. Replace `alert(t);` with `console.info(t)` or `console.info(t.length)` and check output in Chrome and Firebug (for FF) console

Comment: The `alert()` dialogues are designed to hold a limited amount of text so it's not surprising that some browsers truncate very long texts rather than adding scroll bars. In Firefox you should be using Firebug to inspect variables. Also, if you are getting an error message, you should post it here.

Comment: @Andrew,@ Álvaro G. Vicario : Sorry it my sentence problem. I have edited question. There's no matter for alert. Actual problem that I am not getting full string when I parse it to json.

Comment: @Yank: Can you check in Firebug in `Net` tab this XML response. Is full xml file loaded? Response does have Content-Length header or chunked is used? If header is found, then it value is valid?

Comment: @Andrew: I get full string in xml response. And I think its bug of Firefox. I get to know that from your posted link. But at last I got solution see marked answer.**Now Question is.. Is posted function well for performance point of view ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this..

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194231

```
function nodeValue(xmlTag){
 if(xmlTag.firstChild.textContent && xmlTag.normalize) {
  xmlTag.normalize(xmlTag.firstChild);
  content=xmlTag.firstChild.textContent;
  } else if(xmlTag.firstChild.nodeValue) {
   content=xmlTag.firstChild.nodeValue;
  } else {
   content=null;
  }
 return content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.alert) dialog truncates the number of characters in many browsers. This is by design, since a large alert window would be unwieldy.

The best solution is to use [`console.log(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Web_Console#The_console_object), which will print the data to Firebug/Developer Tools.

Comment: @ Eric:Sorry it my sentence problem. I have edited question. There's no matter for alert. Actual problem that I am not getting full string when I parse it to json.

Comment: @Yank: How do you know that you're not getting the full string?

Comment: @ Eric:Using Firebug so from that I get to know